# mvc c# jquery updating a section of the view if record exist else update table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm seeking advice (as usual) as to how to approach this functionality. I have a page that has edit boxes where in the user submits the page with input with the sole purpose of saving it into a record. But what I want to do (to avoid duplicates) is to search the table first for any SIMILAR records and if there are any similar ones, I would like to return it to the user (on the same view) and ask, do you want to use these records instead of saving a new one?

So I have a view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(function(){
         $('.submit-link').click(function(){
             /** not sure how to handle this **/
         });
      });
   });
</script>


<% using(Html.Beginform()){%>
   <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
   <button type="submit" value="register name" class="submit-link">Submit</button>
<%}%>

<div class="search-results"></div>
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult New(){
   return View();
}


[HttpPOst]

public ActionResult New(FormCOllection collection){
   try{
    Profile profile = new Profile();
    TryupdateModel(profile);
    context.Profile.Add(profile);
    context.SaveChanges();
   }
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
   return View();
}
```

So my dilema is, im not sure if:

1. I should post it to the "New" action and then do a search in the middle of it , if records exist, i should return a json format data so i can display it seamlessly using jquery else save it then redirect to the same page.
2. Or, should i just point the whole thing to a json action that will process the search, if it finds something, return to the same page else save then return.

my problem with the latter is that, it will need a GET action, which i'm not sure is good practice if i have a get, then a seperate JSon type method in the controller. Does that make sense?

Or maybe I just need someone to point me to another type of solution

Any help is appreciated! thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Why dont use the [jQuery Autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) to populate the existing items as the User Types. So if User types an exisiting your Autocomplete will shows the options and user will select it. Now When user selects from an existing one ( from the autocomplete suggestions), you know you do not need to save it as new.

This is less work for the User

Comment: you mean like a google auto complete? won't that hit the database too much? how do you generate the existing list and then show it on the text box?

Comment: @gdubs; Yes. You can cache the data. So that it wont hit the db every time. It is easy to implement. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: ok, followup question. what if i have another object (a dropdownlist) that is relevant to the search. i was thinking if the user tabs out of the last editbox then populate the dropdown with the corresponding value connected to the searched values. problem is,what if they use their mouse to click the dropdown itself. (hope that makes sense.)

Answer (score 1):

I would just do the former. If the record exists, return Json, otherwise return a redirect. I don't see anything wrong with having more than one kind of ActionResult returned in the same method. Maybe somebody else out there thinks it's sloppy, but I don't.

I've seen things like this in a lot of projects:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MethodName()
{
    ....
    if(error)
        return Json(new { Error = "Error!" });
    else
        return RedirectToAction("NextStep");
}
```

Comment: so when i return a json, how do i handle that on my getjson() function? i can't seem to make it work. it points me to a different page that shows the json results...

Comment: @gdubs, are you using jQuery to post to the controller? Could you please provide the code you are using to make the post call with and what you're doing to handle it?

Comment: well, im trying to just use post. when you click the submit button inside the form. that's when my dilema comes in, should i be using jquery to handle that instead of relying on the post submit of the page?

Answer (score 1):

How about 1b? always redirect,do check server side, if similar exist redirect to Page showing similars otherwise redirect to the after-save Page. This way you are decoupling one scenario from the other, easier to maintain. Only con is the extra round trip