# mvc entity framework trying to deal with duplicates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

So I'm trying to figure out how to handle duplicates, and one way I thought of is like redesignating the type to the same type

eg

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int? RemappingId {get;set;}

    public virtual Employee Remapping {get;set;}
}
```

so, basically, anyone can register but since I can't do any validations on this part if somebody accidentally saves a duplicate Employee, I plan to have some admin page to map the duplicate employee to like a "main" employee.

But I'm getting this error:

> unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types the principal end of this association must be explicitly
>   configured using either fluent API or data annotations

So I'm not sure if that's the right way of dealing with duplicates, if not please do point me to the right direction. And if it is acceptable, any chance you can help me stop the error?

Thanks!

Much appreciated!

Comment: This feels like really poor application design. What exactly are you trying to acheive and why could there be duplicates? Perhaps the problem should be directed at duplicates prevention rather then handling them.

Comment: well, i agree, but in this case i have an application that deals with promoters having clients that are not committed to registering with an email so they can't have accounts (that would be th main way to deal with duplicates). the promoters can't force their clients to have site accounts cuz some of them would register kids. and promoters would have multiple events in a year. and those kids sometimes registers maybe once or more in several years (they're not sure). so to handle that they would either need to search first and if there's no existing record found they'll add a new one. but..

Comment: if let's say the search functionality didn't catch the criteria/filter then they might end up registering a duplicate record. this is where this thing comes in where they have to deal with duplicates. only thing i can think of is mapping them back to a chosen "master" or "main" record where all duplicates gets mapped to..

Comment: "if let's say the search functionality didn't catch the criteria/filter", then it is NOT a duplicate...?

Comment: true. but here's a scenario, let's say there's an employee named Fname = Anderson Lname = da Silva. and promoter says, somebody registered this Fname = Anderson da Lname = Silva. registration goes through and then there's a duplicate. same goes with Fname = Samir de Lname = Canto and then a new one comes in Fname = Samir de Lname = Canto Dias.

Comment: So you concatenate the first and last name entered in the form to save it as "Full Name" in database? This is a terrible idea. Keep them seperated in the database if you ask them seperated... But if you really want that, why dont you concatenate the first and last name then validate for duplicates in you controller?

Comment: Please post your form view and controller action.

Comment: Ok, so i actually asked this on another thread. But they are completely related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892914/mvc-c-sharp-jquery-updating-a-section-of-the-view-if-record-exist-else-update-ta/11969811#comment15955254_11969811

Answer (score 0):

**So I'm not sure if that's the right way of dealing with duplicates** : Yes, it really is not a good way to do it. and you know it too :)

**How I would suggest you do it**

As you are working with "Employees" I am assuming there will be some id which will be unique to the Employee, (like an EmployeeID). So by making such an id as a primary key, you can do a simple ifExists check for this and show a appropriate message on the view.

**Update :** 
If there is nothing unique for an employee(not even email or employeeId etc), then according to me your database design is faulty. But that again is my *personal* opinion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok my bad, I forgot to say that this gets saved into the database. and this is connected to statistics of the "Employees" like amount events gone to, amount of work done, etc. so if there's a user record who registered for an event (w/o email) this month and then registers again 2 or 3 years after there will be 2 records. and for reporting purposes you want to get the stats of the 2 records (i hope that made sense.)

Comment: if there is nothing unique for an employee(not even email), then according to me your database design is faulty. But that again is my personal opinion.

Comment: i agree. that's what we were talking about on another answer.